# How can I pass MatrixCombinationsParameterValue with simple filter in groovy pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I have a job with matrix project, I added ElasticAxis name:label
I also added a matrix combinations parameter name: labelFilter
I want to run the job from groovy pipeline with filter  label == "PA16"

This call is not working for me:

```
[$class: 'MatrixCombinationsParameterValue', name: 'labelFilter', value: 'label=="PA16"']
```

**The question is: What is the correct syntax to call the matrix combinations parameter?**

I have few branches, each branch should run with specific label, the pipeline gets the branch name and run a job in jenkins with the name of the label. Lets say I want to run the job with the label "PA16" so I add this code to groovy pipeline file:

```
build job: 'test_matrix', 
    parameters: [
        string(name: 'RndBranch', value: RndBranch),
        string(name: 'BuildNumber', value: PAVersion),
        string(name: 'Auto_Build_Path', value: autoFolder),
        string(name: 'Installer_folder', value: Installer_folder),
        string(name: 'RabbitMQ_Server', value: rabbitMQServer),             
        string(name: 'QueName', value: qName),
        [$class: 'MatrixCombinationsParameterValue', name: 'labelFilter', filter: 'label=="PA16"']
    ]
```

Comment: Please, give more information. More code at least. What did you try to solve the problem?

Comment: I added more details in the question

Answer (score 0):

For Jenkins pipeline please use matrix instead. For example:

```
stage ('TestMatrix') {
    matrix  {
        axes {
            axis {
                name 'labelFilter'
                values 'PA16', 'PA17', 'PA18'
            }
            axis {
                name 'otherFilter'
                values 'Filter1', 'Filter2', 'Filter3'
            }
        }
        stages {
            stage ('Doing what you want') {
                 steps { echo "Doing what I want"}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

You can read more at following document about [matrix](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#declarative-matrix) or [here](https://www.jenkins.io/blog/2019/11/22/welcome-to-the-matrix/)